# Applying KeyDrop to a String Pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

After mining some text and computing the WordCounts, I want to KeyDrop all of the elements whose keys are not words. Is there a way to apply KeyDrop to a match string pattern or regular expression? Maybe something that looks similar to this:

```
In[1]:=  KeyDrop[<|000 -> 2, .60 -> 1, .04348 -> 1, able -> 1|>, _Real]

Out[1]=  <|able -> 1|>
```

Comment: `KeySelect` might be better: `KeySelect[...your data..., Not@NumericQ[#]&]`. `KeyDrop` seems to be more closely related to `Drop` which works with elements rather than patterns, so you could first filter the keys then apply `KeyDrop` e.g. `KeyDrop[yourdata, #]&@Select[Keys@yourdata,NumericQ[#]&]`, but this is just a round about way of doing the same.

Comment: What is `000` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have also have strings that are not words you may use [`DictionaryWordQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DictionaryWordQ.html).

```
assoc = <|000 -> 2, .60 -> 1, .04348 -> 1, "able" -> 1, "24km" -> 3|>;
KeySelect[assoc, Quiet[DictionaryWordQ[#, IgnoreCase -> True]] &]
```

> ```
> <|"able" -> 1|>
> ```

[`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) is used because it complains when give numbers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great answer and exactly what I was looking for. Although, C.E.'s answer worked as well, there were still some Greek and math symbols that remained present.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

`KeySelect` can be used the way N.J.Evans uses it in his comment, or also like this:

```
assoc = <|000 -> 2, .60 -> 1, .04348 -> 1, able -> 1|>;

KeySelect[assoc, MatchQ[Except[_Real]]]
```

> `<|0 -> 2, able -> 1|>`

Similarly, `KeySelect[assoc, StringMatchQ[pattern]]` can be used for string patterns, and it also accepts `RegularExpression` if you want to use that.